# Why flutter http response in web missing headers?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-http, dart-http

I am making a simple flutter app using http package.
I am trying to send a (post) login request, and the httpresponse is missing all the headers!
this works fine in ios simulator but in chrome as you can see there are only 2 headers available;
[image]

[image]

What is wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**I have the following:**

Response headers web:

"Origin":"http://localhost:57986"

**Example code:**

```
Future<File> downloadFile(String url, String pathFile) async {
     File file = new File(pathFile);
     var request = await http.post(Uri.parse(url), encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf8'), headers: {
       "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
       "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, HEAD",
     });
     if (request.statusCode == 200) {
       Map<String, String> headers = request.headers;
       if (headers.containsKey("Origin")) {
         var origin = headers['Origin'];
         print("your result: " + origin.toString());
       }
       file.writeAsBytes(request.bodyBytes);
     }
     return file;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the header param `"Access-Control-Expose-Headers" = "*"` from the server side did the trick.

Please see the issue detail here: https://github.com/dart-lang/http/issues/726#issuecomment-1433169316